# java.sql.SQLException: No database selected

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc

as above i have a problem to "select the database"

i am using xampp, there i created a database in MySQL and named it "employees"

This is my java code:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
 Connection conn = null;
 Statement stmt = null;
 try{
  //STEP 2: Register JDBC driver
  Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

  //STEP 3: Open a connection
  System.out.println("Connecting to database...");
  conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost?user=root&password=");

  //STEP 4: Execute a query
  System.out.println("Creating statement...");
  stmt = conn.createStatement();
  String sql;
  sql = "SELECT id, first, last, age FROM employees";
  ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
```

As seen in 'sql' I try to reach the database, using `FROM employees`

I am new to programming with databases.
Do i need to find the path of the database? how and where can i find it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your connection string to make it connect to the right database on localhost

```
conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/employees?user=root&password=");
```

Alternatively you can specify the "full" path to the tables, i.e. `database.tablename`:

```
sql = "SELECT id, first, last, age FROM employees.employees";
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the database you want to use in the connection string:

```
conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/employees?user=root&password=");
```