# JDBC Inner Join java.sql.SQLException: No database selected

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have been trying to get this inner join working with JDBC, Tried it with different formats and it still not returning anything.Below is the current version of the code and the error. 
Edit
Adding more code for context. The program already many working JDBC connection, for some reason I cant seems to get this inner join statement to work.Addint my ConnectionConfig if it helps to clear up any issue.

Code from ConnectionConfig

```
    try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection
                ("********","*********","******");

    } catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return connection;
}
```

Inner join preparedStatemte that is returning errors

```
        PreparedStatement myStatPizzaPlace = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT reviewers.reviewer_name," +
                "reviewers.reviewer_notes, pizzas.* " +
                "FROM (reviewers inner join pizzas on (pizzas.idPizza = reviewers.idPizza))");
```

java.sql.SQLException: No database selected

Comment: Please look at the following post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26496408/java-sql-sqlexception-no-database-selected

Comment: Please post a [mcve], and include your connection string and the full exception stacktrace. Note that you have tagged both MySQL and Microsoft SQL Server, please choose the appropriate tag and remove the other.

Comment: Add some update to my issue. The link question with answer is not what is causing my issues

Answer (score 0):

jdbc:mysql://roxy2db.dev.tot.corp.dobby.com/roxy2

This is how a connection URL should look. Check one more u might be missing the DB name after slash  (roxy2)